# Entity Design using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities -

1. Course
2. Module
3. Timeline
   Course is an independent entity with following attributes:
   Course - (id Integer Primary Key, course_name)

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   Integer courseId;
   @Column(name = "course_name")
   String course_name;

Next up is another entity Module,
Every row in module is related to one course, and hence there is a one to one relationship between Module and Course.
Module - (module_id, module_name, module_type, duration)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "module_id")
Integer module_id;
@Column(name = "module_name")
String module_name;
@Column(name = "duration")
Integer duration;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="timeline_id", nullable=false)
private Timeline timeline;
```

Now, next is a timeline entity, which is also related to course i.e every timeline id belongs to one course id, but one timeline id can belong to multiple module_ids, and hence below code:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "timeline_id")
Integer timelineId;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "timeline" )
private List<Module> module;
@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Course course;
```

Can you please tell me what is the error over here.
**ModuleRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface ModuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Module, Integer>{
    public List<Module> findAllByTimelineTimelineId(Integer timelineId);
}
```

**IModuleService**

```
public interface IModuleService {
     public List<Module> findByTimelineId(Integer timelineId);
}
```

**ModuleServiceImpl**

```
public List<Module> findByTimelineId(Integer timelineId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return moduleRepo.findAllByTimelineTimelineId(timelineId);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/gettimeline/{timeline_id}")
             public List<Module> findByTimelineId(@PathVariable Integer timeline_id){
                    return moduleService.findByTimelineId(timeline_id);
            }
```

Now when I run this url in Postman: `http://localhost:8083/gettimeline/1`

I get an infinite loop, I am unable to decode the error, also is there any problem with OneToMany mapping, I am new to JPA:

```
[{"module_id":1,"module_name":"Sleep","duration":10,"timeline":{"timelineId":1,"module":[{"module_id":1,"module_name":"Sleep","duration":10,"timeline":{"timelineId":1,"module":[{"module_id":1,"module_name":"Sleep","duration":10,"timeline":{"timelineId":1,"module":[{"module_id":1,"module_name":"Sleep","duration":10,"timeline":{"timelineId":1,"module":[{"module_id":1,"module_name":"Sleep","duration":10,"timeline":{"timelineId":1,"module":[
```

Please help, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi. The infinite loop issue is caused by the one-to-many relation. You should implement view model classes where the owning side VM has a collection of the many-side, but not the other way around. If you add the error message you get for your repo code, I can have a look into it. BR

Comment: Hey @RoarS. there's no error actually. There's an infinite loop as given above. I am new to JPA, can you please elaborate on what you said. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi. Added classes in my answer below. Please note that I included only the relevant code, you can add more fields to the VM classes.

Comment: To avoid infinite loop you need to fetch an entity lazily. For this, modify your entity relationship annotation by defining the fetch type like @OneToMany( mappedBy = "timeline", fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) and @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) and also add @Transactional annotation to your service implementation class to get lazily  referenced entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop issue is caused by the one-to-many relation. There are several ways of fixing this, but I find view model classes like shown below as the cleanest approach.

Please note that the owning side of the one-to-many relation is not included in the code below, only the many-to-one. This can be done the other way around, but from your code, I guess this is what you want.

TimelineVM class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimelineVM {

    private Integer timelineId;

    public TimelineVM(Timeline timeline) {
        this.timelineId = timeline.getTimelineId();
    }
}
```

ModuleVM class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ModuleVM {

    private Integer module_id;
    private String module_name;
    private Integer duration;
    private TimelineVM timeline;

    public ModuleVM(Module module) {
        this.module_id = module.getModule_id();
        this.module_name = module.getModule_name();
        this.duration = module.getDuration();
        this.timeline = new TimelineVM(module.getTimeline());
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping("/gettimeline/{timeline_id}")
public List<ModuleVM> findByTimelineId(@PathVariable Integer timeline_id){
  return moduleService.findByTimelineId(timeline_id).stream().map(ModuleVM::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```